# Issue with JAXB XMLAdapter marshalling

Tags: java, marshalling, jaxb2, xmladapter

I have a requirement to generate an `XML` file with below format using `JAXB2`, It has both ***Fixed*** and ***Variable*** xml content.

**What is the Constraint?**

The content of Variable `XML` Part should be one of the 5 different `XML schema`( planned to have `JAXB2.0` implemented 5 different java classes to generate it) which is need to be embedded in the fixed `XML` content.

**XML Format:**

```
<user_info>
  <header>     //Fixed XML Part
     <msg_id>..</msg_id>
     <type>...</type>
  </header>
  <user_type>    //  Variable XML content
                      // (userType : admin, reviewer, auditer, enduser, reporter)
    ........  
  </user_type>
</user_info>
```

**What I tried ?**

I have created a `JAXB` annotated Java classes for the above `XML metadata`. For the variable XML part, I used common Parent class (`BaseUserType`) which was extended by all 5 different Classes `<user_type>`. And tried to Override the `marshall(..)` operation using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. (as below)

**JAXB Annotated Class:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="user_info")
public class UserInfo {

    private Header header;  //reference to JAXB annotated Class Header.class

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CustomXMLAdapter.class)
    private BaseUserType userType; // Base class - acts as a common Type
                                    //  for all 5 different UserType JAXB annotated Classes

    // Getters setters here..
    // Also tried to declare JAXB annotations at Getter method
}
```

**Custom XML Adapter Class:**

```
public class CustomXMLAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Writer, BaseInfo> { 
       private Marshaller marshaller=null; 

        @Override 
        public BaseInfo unmarshal(Writer v) throws Exception { 
            // Some Implementations here...
        }

        @Override 
        public Writer marshal(BaseInfo v) throws Exception { 
                OutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                Writer strResult = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream); 
                if(v instanceof CustomerProfileRequest){ 
                    getMarshaller().marshal((CustomerProfileRequest)v, strResult ); 
                } 
                return strResult; 
        }

        private Marshaller getMarshaller() throws JAXBException{ 
                if(marshaller==null){ 
                        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Admin.class, Reviewer.class, Enduser.class, Auditor.class, Reporter.class);
                        marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller(); 
                } 
                return marshaller; 
        } 
}
```

**Where I'm Struggling now?.**

I'm not facing any errors or warnings, the `XML` is being generated (as shown below). But the output is not the expected one. It *doesn't embeds the Variable XML part with Fixed one correctly*.

**Output**

```
 <user_info>
        <header> 
           <msg_id>100</msg_id>
           <type>Static</type>
        </header>
        <user_type/> // Empty Element, even though we binded the value properly.
    </user_info>
```

**My Questions are :**

1. Why the `JAXB marshallers` could not embeds the "`CustomXMLAdapter`" marshalled content with Parent one `(UserInfo.class)`.
2. Do we have an **any alternative option** in `JAXB` to do this Simple?
3. How to specify the `BoundType`, `ValueType` in `XMLAdapter`. Is there any specific Type to be given in order to Embed the content to Parent Class Marshalling?

Comment: +1 for well presented question

Answer (score 1):

An `XmlAdapter` works by allowing you to convert from your domain object, to another value object that JAXB can better handle for the purposes of Marshalling/Unmarshalling.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

If all the model objects from the other schemas are really sub classes of `BaseUserType`, then all you need to do is make the `JAXBContext` aware of them.  You can do this when you create the `JAXBContext` by having a colon separated String with all the package names.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.common:com.example.foo:com.example.bar");
```